# iOS Augmented Reality and geographical lines

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality

I have begun working on an augmented reality app that needs to show the user a geographically defined boundary. I began by looking at the [Augmented Reality iOS Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/146436/augmented-reality-ios-tutorial-location-based-2), and have that working well for points of interest.

I now would like to show suburb boundaries to the user. This would require taking a vector, taking its projection from the user's current position, and knowing where on the screen to place it. I'm wondering if I'll need to use ARKit to achieve this? And how the code to take a path from `(x1,y) to (x2,y2)` to a defined line on-screen might look.